# Sybase SQL Anywhere 10 - Logging SQL Statements

Tags: sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

Does anyone know of a mechanism in Sybase ASA 9 / Sybase SQL Anywhere 10 to log the SQL statements that it executes?

I have a web application that is misbehaving due to some apparently missing data, but everything looks fine.

If we were able to log the offending statement we could probably get things sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [`-zr` server switch](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1001/en/dbdaen10/da-zr-database-dbengine.html). You can also look at the [sa_server_option](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1001/en/dbrfen10/rf-sa-server-option-system-sysproc.html) system procedure to change the setting while the server is running.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was after :)